# How to override the magento 2 createpost controller?

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.3

I overridden the `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost` controller using preference in `di.xml` and want to add a collection using factory method but always I get

> Type Error occurred when creating object

Even I removed the generated folder and done di compile still facing same issue.

My di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost" type="Vendor\Modulename\Override\Account\CreatePost"/>
```

My Controller.

```
    <?php

        namespace Vendor\Modulename\Override\Account;

        use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
        use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
        use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
        use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
        use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
        use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
        use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
        use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
        use Magento\Customer\Helper\Address;
        use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory;
        use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
        use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
        use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
        use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
        use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
        use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;

        class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address
     */
    protected $addressHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
     */
    protected $formFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory
     */
    protected $subscriberFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $regionDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $addressDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Registration
     */
    protected $registration;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $customerDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
     */
    protected $customerUrl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $escaper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor
     */
    protected $customerExtractor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
     */
    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    private $accountRedirect;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param Address $addressHelper
     * @param UrlFactory $urlFactory
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
     * @param RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory
     * @param AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory
     * @param CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerUrl
     * @param Registration $registration
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        Address $addressHelper,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        Registration $registration,
        Escaper $escaper,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->addressHelper = $addressHelper;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        $this->regionDataFactory = $regionDataFactory;
        $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
        $this->customerDataFactory = $customerDataFactory;
        $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->registration = $registration;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
        $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $customerSession, $scopeConfig, $storeManager, $accountManagement, $addressHelper, $formFactory, $subscriberFactory, $regionDataFactory, $addressDataFactory, $customerDataFactory, $customerUrl, $registration, $escaper, $customerExtractor, $dataObjectHelper, $accountRedirect, $formKeyValidator=null, $urlFactory->create());
    }

            /**
             * Retrieve cookie manager
             *
             * @deprecated 100.1.0
             * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
             */
            private function getCookieManager()
            {
                if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
                    $this->cookieMetadataManager = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::class
                    );
                }
                return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
            }

            /**
             * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
             *
             * @deprecated 100.1.0
             * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
             */
            private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
            {
                if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
                    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::class
                    );
                }
                return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
            }

            /**
             * Add address to customer during create account
             *
             * @return AddressInterface|null
             */
            protected function extractAddress()
            {
                if (!$this->getRequest()->getPost('create_address')) {
                    return null;
                }

                $addressForm = $this->formFactory->create('customer_address', 'customer_register_address');
                $allowedAttributes = $addressForm->getAllowedAttributes();

                $addressData = [];

                $regionDataObject = $this->regionDataFactory->create();
                foreach ($allowedAttributes as $attribute) {
                    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                    $value = $this->getRequest()->getParam($attributeCode);
                    if ($value === null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    switch ($attributeCode) {
                        case 'region_id':
                            $regionDataObject->setRegionId($value);
                            break;
                        case 'region':
                            $regionDataObject->setRegion($value);
                            break;
                        default:
                            $addressData[$attributeCode] = $value;
                    }
                }
                $addressDataObject = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
                $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                    $addressDataObject,
                    $addressData,
                    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface::class
                );
                $addressDataObject->setRegion($regionDataObject);

                $addressDataObject->setIsDefaultBilling(
                    $this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false)
                )->setIsDefaultShipping(
                    $this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false)
                );
                return $addressDataObject;
            }

            /**
             * @inheritDoc
             */
            public function createCsrfValidationException(
                RequestInterface $request
            ): ?InvalidRequestException {
                /** @var Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($url));

                return new InvalidRequestException(
                    $resultRedirect,
                    [new Phrase('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.')]
                );
            }

            /**
             * @inheritDoc
             */
            public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
            {
                return null;
            }

            /**
             * Create customer account action
             *
             * @return void
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
             */
            public function execute()
            {
    }
    }
```

Comment: How did you added collection? Can you please share your code?

Comment: Atleast a helper is fine for me. I added that collection in helper I just need to call that helper in constructor.

Comment: Can you add your di.xml and controller code with file path?

Comment: If you want to add your collection in constructor. You should call parent constructor with required params.

Comment: I will check the code which you sent and get back to you.

Comment: I'm not sure my code is correct, but correct flow should be like below answer

Comment: No its not working. Its still showing same error.

Comment: @SukumarGorai I kept my di.xml inside the etc folder, and for controller this is the path app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Override/Account/CreatePost.php

Comment: Can you update your code please?

Comment: @Rising Can you please share your code

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: You have updated the code but removed the collection which cause the error. Can you please let us know what collection you want to add here and what will be the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please update __construct code and use below code format

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
    Address $addressHelper,
    UrlFactory $urlFactory,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
    AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
    CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
    CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
    Registration $registration,
    Escaper $escaper,
    CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
    Validator $formKeyValidator = null
) {
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);
    $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $customerSession,
        $scopeConfig,
        $storeManager,
        $accountManagement,
        $addressHelper,
        $urlFactory,
        $formFactory,
        $subscriberFactory,
        $regionDataFactory,
        $addressDataFactory,
        $customerDataFactory,
        $customerUrl,
        $registration,
        $escaper,
        $customerExtractor,
        $dataObjectHelper,
        $accountRedirect
    );
}
```

Comment: Great thanks yar. What's the mistake I done?

Comment: @Rising sound good! You have added formKeyValidator and accountRedirect in the parent construct.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your helper object by below method.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Address;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;

class Yourclass extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address
     */
    protected $addressHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
     */
    protected $formFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory
     */
    protected $subscriberFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $regionDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $addressDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Registration
     */
    protected $registration;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $customerDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
     */
    protected $customerUrl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $escaper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor
     */
    protected $customerExtractor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
     */
    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    private $accountRedirect;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $formKeyValidator;

    protected $_customHelper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        Address $addressHelper,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        Registration $registration,
        Escaper $escaper,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null,
        \Vendor\Module\etc\Helper $customHelper
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context, 
            $customerSession, 
            $scopeConfig, 
            $storeManager, 
            $accountManagement, 
            $addressHelper, 
            $formFactory, 
            $subscriberFactory, 
            $regionDataFactory, 
            $addressDataFactory, 
            $customerDataFactory, 
            $customerUrl, 
            $registration, 
            $escaper, 
            $customerExtractor, 
            $urlFactory->create(), 
            $dataObjectHelper, 
            $accountRedirect, 
            $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class)
        );

        $this->_customHelper = $customHelper;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

    }
}
```